# Papyrus font exists on iPad but not iPhone

Tags: ios, fonts

My app uses papyrus font.

In the iPad simulator it works perfectly. In both of the iPhone simulators (standard and retina) it doesn't seem to have this font. It just uses a stock system font.

I have just tested on both an iPhone and an iPad, and the results identical to the simulator.

What is the deal here?   is there any workaround? Can I package this font with the app?  If so, how?

As a related issue, this papyrus font refuses to display unusual characters. I require for example ∫ and ŋ.  These get displayed in a stock system font.  I guess the font doesn't have symbols for extended Unicode characters... what is my best bet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPhone and iPad ship with [different sets of fonts](http://iosfonts.com/), which is a bit strange. If you want to bundle this font with your app, you will need to obtain a licence to do so from one of the [foundries that distribute it](http://www.fonts.com/findfonts/detail.htm?productid=173439).

As for other characters, you're correct---the Papyrus font only supports characters used in European languages. If you don't like the system's default fall-back font, you will need to supply another.